# Is the time derivative of the adjoint equal to the adjoint of the time derivative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, differentiation, time-evolution

This is hopefully straightforward. Starting from the Schrödinger equation as an axiom, one obtains the operator differential equation for the $U$ such that $| \psi(t) \rangle = U(t,t_0) | \psi(t_0) \rangle$ which says
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(t,t_0) = -(i/\hbar) H(t) U(t,t_0) \quad .$$
The author then says that the above equation implies
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} U^\dagger U = (i/\hbar)(U^\dagger H^\dagger U - UHU^\dagger) \quad , $$
which seems to require that the adjoint and time derivative operators commute:
$$\left (\frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(t,t_0) \right)^\dagger = (i/\hbar) U^\dagger(t,t_0)H(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} U^\dagger(t,t_0) \quad .$$
Should this fact be obvious to me? Is it easy to supply a proof?

Comment: Which author, book, page etc...

Comment: Well, since $U$ is unitary, i.e. $U^\dagger U=1$, we have that $\partial_t U^\dagger U  = \partial_t UU^\dagger= 0$. Applying the product rule yields $\dot U^\dagger U +U^\dagger \dot U =0$ and thus $\dot U^\dagger  =  - U^\dagger \dot U U^\dagger = +i\hbar U^\dagger H$.

Comment: @TobiasFünke This is Ballentine page 89 in his *Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development*, though I think this is a very common argument. Thank you also for your answer, I think that does it for me.

Comment: You should add this to the question. It does not matter whether or not this is standard; if you refer to a reference then state it explicitly. BTW: My argument does not really work if you don't know already that $U$ is unitary...because it seems that this is what the author is aiming at. Also, comparing your second equation with that given in the book, at least one of them must be wrong; I haven't checked.

Comment: You are right, I can't use your argument at this point. Thank you for pointing that out. @TobiasFünke

Comment: Think about how derivatives are defined as limits. Then think about how the adjoint operation is a linear map on operators.

Comment: @EE18 Yes; for this reason it is important to place the question in context (e.g. "the author wants to show that $U$ is unitary; to do so, they compute...) and give the exact reference...

Comment: @Prahar Please see my comment to Mike Stone. The last step in which the limit and the adjoint "operation" commute is not obvious, at least to me. Mike Stone mentions topological considerations and, while I'm not sure what is being hinted at there, it doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Noted for the future, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $A-B=C$ then from the linearity and antilinearity of the inner product we use to define the adjoint we have  $(\lambda A)^\dagger = \lambda^* A^\dagger$ and $A^\dagger-B^\dagger=C^\dagger$. Thus  subtration and muliplication by real numbers commute with adjointing. Now derivatives are just subtractions and divisions  ---  so *yes* they commute with the adjointing operatation.

Comment: When you mention real numbers $\lambda$ in particular, that's in your setup for the limit operation right? Wouldn't you further need to argue that the adjoint operation "commutes with the limit", whatever that means?

Comment: @EE18 Everything thus far is only at a formal level, i.e. not rigorous. For example, one has to specify in what topology the derivative is meant to be etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm capable of being "fully rigorous", but are you saying it's true or not in general true that $ dA^\dagger /dt = lim_{h \to 0} (A^\dagger(t+h)-A^\dagger(t))/h = lim_{h \to 0} ((A(t+h)-A(t))/h)^\dagger = (lim_{h \to 0} ((A(t+h)-A(t))/h))^\dagger = (dA/dt)^\dagger$?

Comment: The limit for differentiating $U$  is the content of *Stone's theorem* (No relative!).

Comment: Noted, and touche :)

Comment: Well, but Stone's theorem assumes that $U$ is unitary; this is what the author wants to state/show.

Comment: Would it be possible to comment on the problem mentioned by @TobiasFünke ?

Comment: I'm not usre what the issue is.   For finite dimensional $H$ the limit is no more complicatde than ordinary calculus.   For the infinite dimensional case, as  long as $H$ is self-adjoint then $U(t)$ is unitary by using Stone's theorem in one direction.   The question of whether the  limit giving the derivative of $U^\dagger$ works is answered by the converse version  of the theorem.  Appeals to the sophisicated functional analysis in  Stone is  surely  overkill in the context that the question was asked though.  The definition of the adjoint is all that is required.

Comment: The issue (at least to me) is that we take the derivative of $U^\dagger$ (in the middle equation in the attached picture) *before* we establish that $U$ is unitary. @TobiasFünke do you agree that that is the problem?

Comment: @mikestone please let me know if you get the chance! I do understand if you don't have time to, though.

Comment: I don't have anything else useful to say. The finite dimensional case is already sorted and the infinite dimensional is rather technical.